# How to convert mmm-yy(Jan-85) date format into yyyy-mm--dd (1985-01-02)date format in R?

Tags: r

I want to convert mmm-yy(Jan-85)  date format into yyyy-mm-dd (1985-01-02)date format in R.

Comment: check this out: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925731/r-convert-month-and-2-digit-year-into-date/57926945#57926945)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `paste` the day and convert it to `Date` class with `as.Date` and the appropriate `format`

```
as.Date(paste0("Jan-85", "-02"), "%b-%y-%d")
#[1] "1985-01-02"
```

Comment: I have a column named Date which has a series of Dates ie,Jan-18,feb-18, Mar-18 and so. I still have trouble converting the entire column into 1980-01-01 format. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @Anjaly Not clear from the comments.  Can you dput the input

Comment: Date
Feb-88
Mar-88
Apr-88
May-88
Final output should be in the following format
2/2/1988
2/3/1988
2/4/1988
2/5/1988

Comment: Thank you so much . It works.